# MySQL Stored Procedure Search another table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am totally new to Stored Procedures, but know that this could be more efficient than trying to write PHP+MySQL code each time I need to do something like this.

I have two tables.  **CapitalAssets**, **Systems**
I want find all **CapitalAssets.ServerName** that are not null

I have to link the two tables together, the **Systems** table has IP addresses, **hostname**.

I want to (row-by-row) grab **CapitalAssets.ServerName** and search **Systems.hostname**, IF it is found I want to link/print

**CapitalAssests**:  *Systems.id, Systems.hostname, Systems.IP, CapitalAssets.id, CapitalAssets.ServerName*

Here is my start to my stored procedure, It is wrong.  I do not now how to pass the Systems.hostname to do the search (where the ? is)

```
begin
      declare GSATcur cursor for
            'select id,NEName,ManagementAddress FROM GSAT WHERE NEName like ?';

      declare CapitalCurr CURSOR FOR
            'SELECT id,SystemName FROM CapitalAssets WHERE SystemName != ""';

      DECLARE start INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE sysname_not_found BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET sysname_not_found = TRUE;

      OPEN GSATcur;
      OPEN CapitalCur;

      loop1:
            WHILE start < 5 do
                  FETCH SystemName INTO NEName;
                  IF sysname_not_found THEN
                        LEAVE loop1;
                  END IF;

            END WHILE;

      CLOSE CapitalCur;
      CLOSE GSATcur;
END;
```

The two tables are in the same dB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" grab CapitalAssets.ServerName and search Systems.hostname, IF it is found I want to link/print "

If this is the ultimate goal. Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Systems
WHERE hostname IN ( SELECT DISTINCT(ServerName) 
   FROM CapitalAssets WHERE ServerName IS NOT NULL );
```

---

```
UPDATE CapitalAssets 
INNER JOIN Systems
    ON Systems.hostname = CapitalAssests.ServerName
SET CapitalAssets.ipAddress = Systems.ipAddress;
```

---

```
UPDATE CapitalAssets 
SET ipAddress = ( SELECT ipAddress 
    FROM Systems 
    WHERE  Systems.hostname = CapitalAssests.ServerName );
```

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.  Hmmm, I guess I made it more complicated than it should have been.

Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Now to complicate things (most likely not for you).  I need to perform an update when found.  My table SYSTEMS has a column **ipAddress**.

I want to update **CapitalAssets.ipAddress** with **Systems.ipAddress** when the **Systems.hostname** matches **CapitalAssests.ServerName**

Comment: This is what I have so far showing me both IP address columns:

`SELECT CapitalAssets.id,ServerName,ipAddress,Systems.ipAddress AS Systems_IPAddress from CapitalAssets JOIN Systems on CapitalAssets.ServerName = Systems.hostname WHERE hostname in ( SELECT hostname from Systems );`

Comment: Checkout the UPDATE query in the answer as per your second comment.